# Dockerfile copy files from amazon s3 or another source that needs credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3

I am trying to build a Docker image and I need to copy some files from S3 to the image.

Inside the Dockerfile I am using:

Dockerfile

```
FROM library/ubuntu:16.04
ENV LANG=C.UTF-8 LC_ALL=C.UTF-8

# Copy files from S3 inside docker
RUN aws s3 COPY s3://filepath_on_s3 /tmp/
```

However, `aws` requires AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY.
I know I can probably pass them using `ARG`. But, is it a bad idea to pass them to the image at build time?

How can I achieve this without storing the secret keys in the image?

Answer (score 28):

In my opinion, Roles is the best to delegate S3 permissions to Docker containers.

1. Create role from IAM -> Roles -> Create Role -> Choose the service that will use this role, select EC2 -> Next -> select s3policies and Role should be created.
2. Attach Role to running/stopped instance from Actions-> Instance Settings -> Attach/Replace Role

This worked successfully in Dockerfile:

`RUN aws s3 cp s3://bucketname/favicons /var/www/html/favicons --recursive`

Comment: yes always add relevant roles to provide credentials instead of hard coding creds.

Comment: That's all good for a file that never change. But if you're expecting to always copy the latest version then you're in for troubles as docker can use the layer it has in its cache!

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to build upon @Ankita Dhandha answer.

In the case of Docker you are probably looking to use ECS.

1. IAM Roles are absolutely the way to go.
2. When running locally, locally tailored Docker file and mount your AWS CLI `~/.aws` directory to the root users `~/.aws` directory in the container (*this allows it to use your or a custom IAM user's CLI credentials to mock behavior in ECS for local testing*).

```
# local sytem
from ubuntu:latest

curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
unzip awscliv2.zip
sudo ./aws/install
```

```sh
docker run --mount type=bind,source="~/.aws",target=/root/.aws
```

### Role Types

1. EC2 Instance Roles define the global actions any instance can preform. An example would be having access to S3 to download ecs.config to `/etc/ecs/ecs.config` during your custom `user-data.sh` setup.
2. Use the ECS Task Definition to define a Task Role and a Task Execution Role.
3. Task Roles are used for a running container. An example would be a live web app that is moving files in and out of S3.
4. Task Execution Roles are for deploying the task. An example would be downloading the ECR image and deploying it to ECS, downloading an environment file from S3 and exporting it to the Docker container.

### General Role Propagation

###### In the example of C# SDK there is a list of locations it will look in order to obtain credentials. Not everything behaves like this. But many do so you have to research it for your situation.

*reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/latest/developer-guide/creds-assign.html*

1. Plain text credentials fed into either the target system or environment variables.
2. CLI AWS credentials and a profile set in the `AWS_PROFILE` environment variable.
3. Task Execution Role used to deploy the docker task.
4. The running task will use the Task Role.
5. When the running task has no permissions for the current action it will attempt to elevate into the EC2 instance role.

### Blocking EC2 instance role access

Because of the EC2 instance role commonly needing access for custom system setup such as configuring ECS its often desirable to block your tasks from accessing this role. This is done by blocking the tasks access to the EC2 metadata endpoints which are well known DNS endpoints in any AWS VPC.

*reference: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-container-ec2-metadata/*

###### AWS VPC Network Mode

```sh
# ecs.confg
ECS_AWSVPC_BLOCK_IMDS=true
```

###### Bind Network Mode

```sh
# ec2-userdata.sh

# install dependencies
yum install -y aws-cli iptables-services

# setup ECS dependencies
aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/ecs.config /etc/ecs/ecs.config

# setup IPTABLES
iptables --insert FORWARD 1 -i docker+ --destination 169.254.169.254/32 --jump DROP
iptables --append INPUT -i docker+ --destination 127.0.0.1/32 -p tcp --dport 51679 -j ACCEPT
service iptables save
```

Answer (score 2):

Many people pass in the details through the `args`, which I see as being fine and the way I would personally do it. I think you can overkill certain processes and this I think this is one of them.

Example docker with `args`

```
docker run -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=123 -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=1234
```

Saying that I can see why some companies want to hide this away and get this from a private API or something. This is why AWS have created IAM roles - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html.

Details could be retrieved from the private ip address which the S3 can only access meaning you would never have to store your credentials in your image itself.

Personally i think its overkill for what you are trying to do, if someone hacks your image they can console the credentials out and still get access to those details. Passing them in as `args` is safe as long as you protect yourself as you should anyway.

Comment: The Dockerfile reference warns about using `ARG` and passing --build-args for secrets, because the values appear in the history: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/arg. Anyway to circumvent this?

Comment: No i am afraid history does pass back those args.. so who ever can get access to the docker box can get all the secrets. I guess the question is if they have access to that could they get the secrets anyway? If it is a huge issue look at suggestion 2 i said or maybe something like this could help - https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/

Answer (score -10):

you should configure your credentials on the ~/.aws/credentials file

```
~$ cat .aws/credentials 
[default]
aws_access_key_id = AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAa
aws_secret_access_key = BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
```

Comment: Yeah, I obviously do not want to store my credentials in the Docker image.

Comment: copy the credentials while creating the image and delete them after running the aws commands
if that bothers you then, as part of your image creation you have to create a shell script that copies the aws data to your local disk and then run docker build with a modified Dockerfile that copies the files into the image in a normal way

Comment: Instead of just downvoting, let me explain why this isn't so great - any copy that happens in the Dockerfile saves your credentials to that image.  Anyone with access to that image has access to your AWS credentials.  That is bad and requiring a delete to protect creds is a recipe for accidentally forgetting and/or pushing that image up to an external repo.

Instead, see other answers above.  Either run your image w/ the creds as env vars or mount the `~/.aws/credentials` file when you run your container - that way your credentials won't potentially be cached in a potentially-public place.