# How to interact with s3 bucket from inside a docker container?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, dockerfile, containers

I want to create a Dockerfile which could allow me to interact with s3 buckets from the container . I am not able to build any sample also . Does anyone have a sample dockerfile which I could refer for my case

Comment: What type of interaction you want to achieve with the container. you can run a python program and use boto3 to do it or you can use the aws-cli in shell script to interact with S3. Lot depends on your use case.

Comment: Simple interaction like read write

Comment: This is an experimental use case so any working way is fine for me . Actually my case is to read from an S3 bucket say ABCD and write into another S3 bucket say EFGH .. I have no idea a t all as I have very less experience in this area. DO you have a sample Dockerfile ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51409209/dockerfile-copy-files-from-amazon-s3-or-another-source-that-needs-credentials

Answer (score 1):

It should be straightforward. Create a Docker image with boto installed in it. You can use some of the existing popular image like [boto3](https://hub.docker.com/r/jpbarto/boto3) and have that as the base image in your Dockerfile. You can also start with [alpine](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine) as the base image and install python, boto, etc. Next, you need to inject AWS creds (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY) as environment variables. Once all of that is set, you should be able to interact with the s3 bucket or other AWS services using boto

Comment: What if I have to include two S3 buckets then how will I set the credentials inside the container ? Actually my case is to read from an S3 bucket say ABCD and write into another S3 bucket say EFGH .. I have no idea a t all as I have very less experience in this area. DO you have a sample Dockerfile ?

Comment: You have a few options. a) Use the same AWS creds/ IAM user, which has access to both buckets (less preferred). b) Use separate creds and inject all of them as env vars; in this case, you will initialize separate boto clients for each bucket [initialize boto](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/credentials.html#passing-credentials-as-parameters)